# MongoDB text search does not return anything

Tags: mongodb

One of my collection no longer returns anything on some search values. Here is a console dump to illustrate the probleme :

```
meteor:PRIMARY> db['test'].insert({ sku: 'Barrière' });
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
meteor:PRIMARY> db['test'].insert({ sku: 'Bannière' });
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
meteor:PRIMARY> db['test'].createIndex({ sku: 'text' });
{
        "createdCollectionAutomatically" : false,
        "numIndexesBefore" : 1,
        "numIndexesAfter" : 2,
        "ok" : 1
}
meteor:PRIMARY> db['test'].find({ sku: /ba/i });
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57bbb447fc77800b1e63ba64"), "sku" : "Barrière" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57bbb455fc77800b1e63ba65"), "sku" : "Bannière" }
meteor:PRIMARY> db['test'].find({ $text: { $search: 'ba' } });
meteor:PRIMARY> db['test'].find({ $text: { $search: 'Ba' } });
meteor:PRIMARY>
```

The search returned nothing, even though I clearly added two documents that should match. What's going on? What option/config am I missing?

#### ** Edit **

I tried this query

```
meteor:PRIMARY> db['test'].find({ $or: [ { $text: { $search: 'ba' } }, { sku: { $regex: 'ba', $options: 'i' } } ] });
Error: error: {
    "waitedMS" : NumberLong(0),
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "error processing query: ns=meteor.testTree: $or\n    sku regex /ba/\n    TEXT : query=ba, language=english, caseSensitive=0, diacriticSensitive=0, tag=NULL\nSort:
{}\nProj: {}\n planner returned error: Failed to produce a solution for TEXT under OR - other non-TEXT clauses under OR have to be indexed as well.",
    "code" : 2
}
```

But I'm not sure how I can make an index to search partial values (i.e. using `$regex` or other operator). Using a third party indexer seems overkill to me... Surely there is a way to perform a full-text search, as well as a pattern match at once?

Is my only solution to perform two queries and merge the results manually?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
db['test'].insert({ sku: 'ba ba' });
db['test'].find({ $text: { $search: 'ba' } });
```

Also refer to mongodb document:

**If the search string is a space-delimited string, $text operator performs a logical OR search on each term and returns documents that contains any of the terms.**

I think mongodb $text $search just split the string by space and match the whole word. If you need to search part of the word, you may need to use some other framework for help. Maybe you can also use $regex to do this.

If the only requirement is to query the word by prefix, you can use $regex, it can use index if you are only querying by the prefix. Otherwise if will scan the whole collection.

Comment: well, sure, however you are adjusting the *data* to match the query, while I need a *query* to fetch the data.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I think mongodb didn't get your language, are you using french or what language?I think it's the è making mongodb buggy. I have tried that using Bannièr or Bannière will return your documents. but if it's shorter than Banniè, it won't return. I also tried pure english word, like "hello" , it only return when I use "hello" when I use the $text search.You can try to use $language operation to speciafy the language that you are using.

Comment: If you do need to query "Bannière" by "ba" , or even "an" , you may need to build an index by yourself, mapping "b" ,"B" , "ba", "Ba" ,"an" blah blah all to "Bannière" .  You can also use a third party framework to do the indexing , like sphinx. That's all I know.